# How do I pass reference to active driver between classes

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, nunit

My problem is that when firstname is suppose to be set by the driver in the FetchName method I get an error message that the driver is null. Can I pass the active driver instance in some way so I can continue fetch data?

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestBase
{
    protected IWebDriver driverChrome;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        driverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
    }


    [TearDown]
    public void CleanSite()
    {
        driverChrome.Quit();
    }

}
```

Class "Tests" where I create all my [test] methods.

```
public void tests: Testbase
{
        [Test]
        public void testmethods()
        {
            string blabla = driverChrome.FindElement(By.id("dsd")).Text;
            Reuse.FetchName(out string firstname, out string lastname);
            Assert.isTrue(firstname.equals(lastname));
        } 
}
```

One Class "Reuse" where I have methods that the [test] methods will use multiple times.

```
public class Reuse: Testbase
{
    [Test]
    public void FetchName(out string firstname, out string lastname)
    {
            firstname = driverChrome.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody[last()]/tr/td[2]/div")).Text;
            lastname = driverChrome.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody[last()]/tr/td[2]/div")).Text; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make you driverChrome as a global variable or write a getter setter to get the driver instance.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Reuse` class is not a test case. When you add attribute `[Test]` to the method, the method should contains an assertion. So `Reuse` should not inherit from `Testbase`.
2. If you want to have a class that contains multiple actions, it should be static class.
3. WebDriver is a standalone process. You can use multiple classes or multiple process to access it. They all will get the same WebDriver.

The example below shows how to change the `Reuse` class and how to use it.

```
public static class Reuse
{
    public static IWebDriver driverChrome;
    public static void FetchName(out string firstname, out string lastname)
    {
            firstname = driverChrome.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody[last()]/tr/td[2]/div")).Text;
            lastname = driverChrome.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody[last()]/tr/td[2]/div")).Text; 
    }
}
```

You can call it like this.

```
public void tests: Testbase
{
    [Test]
    public void testmethods()
    {
        string blabla = driverChrome.FindElement(By.id("dsd")).Text;
        Reuse.driverChrome = driverChrome;
        Reuse.FetchName(out string firstname, out string lastname);
        Assert.isTrue(firstname.equals(lastname));
    }
```

}